# Binary Interleaving, Binary Swizzling, Alternating Bits

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, sse

### Problem:

I have a sequence of bits of indices `7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0` and I want to swizzle them the following way :

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0  =  7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
   _____| | | |     | | | |_____
  |    ___| | |     | | |___    |  
  |   |    _| |     | |_    |   |  
  |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |  
  v   v   v   v     v   v   v   v  
_ 3 _ 2 _ 1 _ 0     7 _ 6 _ 5 _ 4 _
       |___________________|
                 |
                 v
          7 3 6 2 5 1 4 0
```

i.e. I want to interleave the bits of the low and high nibbles from a byte.

#### Naive solution:

I can achieve this behavior in C using the following way :

```
int output = 
    ((input & (1 <<  0)) << 0) |
    ((input & (1 <<  1)) << 1) |
    ((input & (1 <<  2)) << 2) |
    ((input & (1 <<  3)) << 3) |
    ((input & (1 <<  4)) >> 3) |
    ((input & (1 <<  5)) >> 2) |
    ((input & (1 <<  6)) >> 1) |
    ((input & (1 <<  7)) >> 0);
```

However it's obviously very clunky.

## Striving for a more elegant solution:

I was wondering if there where something I could do to achieve this behavior faster in less machine instructions. Using SSE for example?

### Some context for curious people :

I use this for packing 2d signed integer vector coordinates into a 1d value that conserves proximity when dealing with memory and caching. The idea is similar to some texture layouts optimization used by some GPUs on mobile devices.
`(i ^ 0xAAAAAAAA) - 0xAAAAAAAA` converts from 1d integer to 1d signed integer with this power of two proximity I was talking about.
`(x + 0xAAAAAAAA) ^ 0xAAAAAAAA` is just the reverse operation, going from 1d signed integer to a 1d integer, still with the same properties.
To have it become 2d and keep the proximity property, I want to alternate the x and y bits.

Comment: I would probably just generate a pre-swizzled lookup table of all 256 chars (covering the entire value space), e.g. `char swiz[256]; for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) swiz[i] = swizzle(i);`

Comment: @paddy Thank you for your answer. I though about that alternative. I'm still wondering if there isn't an instruction that exists that would avoid myself the trouble to have this lookup table in cache.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN)?  It interleaves bits of two 16-bit values.  Presumably you can adapt the method to 4-bit values, although it may be inefficient.  Or maybe you actually want to do it on wider data anyway.

Comment: @paddy Wow now this is something exiting! Basically halves the amount of instructions. I need to have better look into it to fully understand it... However, if it does what I expect then it's definitely a great solution. I'll run some tests and see where it leads. No I do need it for very small vectors as this is connected with GPU limitations. However even that method looks scalable anyway. Thank you very much for your insightful answer.

Comment: Maybe check out the method above it that [interleaves two 8-bit values with 64-bit multiplication](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#Interleave64bitOps).  I presume that you could change that to inteleave two 4-bit values with 32-bit multiplication.  And that may lend itself quite nicely to an efficient SIMD solution such as SSE which you were seeking.

Comment: Sure thing. I will be reading the full website's page as I wasn't aware of if existence up until now. This is gold you've given me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @paddy: Those bithacks never take advantage of stuff like using SSSE3 `pshufb` as a parallel LUT of 4-bit indices, and any byte-broadcasting they do is always with multiplies.  There are probably some ancient AMD k10 CPUs still in use that don't have SSSE3, but if you can require it (or use an alternate implementation when it's not available) that would be good I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to interleave the bits of the low and high nibbles in each byte?  For scalar code a 256-byte lookup table (LUT) is probably your best bet.

For x86 SIMD, SSSE3 `pshufb` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) can be used as a parallel LUT of 16x nibble->byte lookups in parallel.  Use this to unpack a nibble to a byte.

```
__m128i interleave_high_low_nibbles(__m128i v) {
    const __m128i lut_unpack_bits_low = _mm_setr_epi8( 0, 1, 0b00000100, 0b00000101, 
              ...   // dcba -> 0d0c0b0a
     );
    const __m128i lut_unpack_bits_high = _mm_slli_epi32(lut_unpack_bits_low, 1);
                    // dcba -> d0c0b0a0

   // ANDing is required because pshufb uses the high bit to zero that element
   // 8-bit element shifts aren't available so also we have to mask after shifting
    __m128i lo = _mm_and_si128(v, _mm_set1_epi8(0x0f));
    __m128i hi = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi32(v, 4), _mm_set1_epi8(0x0f));

    lo = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_unpack_bits_low, lo);
    hi = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_unpack_bits_high, hi);
    return _mm_or_si128(lo, hi);
}
```

This is not faster than a memory LUT for a single byte, but **it does 16 bytes in parallel**.  `pshufb` is a single-uop instruction on x86 CPUs made in the last decade.  (Slow on first-gen Core 2 and K8.)

Having separate lo/hi LUT vectors means that setup can be hoisted out of a loop; otherwise we'd need to shift one LUT result before ORing together.

Comment: Perfect, this was the kind of things I was looking for. I'm actually working with 16 bits integer, 8 bits was to keep the problem simple. Not that it matters much since this answer can be adapted quite easily.

Comment: @Mendear: Cool.  Note that if you have AVX2, you can do this for both 128-bit lanes at once with `_mm256_shuffle_epi8`.  Or with AVX512BW for `vpermw`, you can do 64-byte chunks using a LUT of 16-bit words instead of 8-bit bytes.  Also, SSE2 does have word shifts, so you can probably save some ANDing, e.g. AND and ANDNOT with `set1_epi16(0x0f0f)` then use `epi16` logical right shifts by 4, 8, and 12.  (And the source operand for `>>12` doesn't need to be masked first)

Comment: @Mendear: brain fart at the end of my last comment: you probably still want to use every byte for each pshufb you do, so shift by 12 wouldn't be useful.  If you want to post an answer or edit mine with your 16-bit interleave, that might be useful for future readers.